# wxWindows 2.4.2 configuration failed saying checking for toolkit... configure: error: Please specify at most one toolkit

Tags: c++, gcc, configuration, wxwidgets, rhel

I am new to Linux environment, we have task to migrate a Windows wxWidgets(version 2.4.2) GUI application to Linux platform(RHEL8 or 8.3).The application is successful on Visual studio 2017&2019(Compiler MSVC++ 14.1 and 14.2) using the wxWindows-2.4.2(very old one). But when i try to build wxWindows2.4.2 on Linux( **g++ (GCC) 8.3.1 20191121 (Red Hat 8.3.1-5)**)

> ../configure --with-gtk=2

at configuration stage process stopped saying

> checking for toolkit... configure: error: Please specify at most one
> toolkit (maybe some are cached in configarg.cache?)

I tried by installing *"Development Tool"* on Linux but getting same thing.

Source: https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/archive/refs/tags/v2.4.2.zip

Comment: Rather than trying to build the 18-year-old wx 2.4.2 on a modern system, install the `wxGTK3-devel` package from `epel` and try to migrate the codebase to use a more modern version of wx. It can be a lot of work, but even if you built 2.4.2 successfully, there most likely would be all kinds of surprises ahead.

Comment: @bhaskar, is there a reason you are using an outdated library?

Comment: There is no specific reason @ Igor/Lauri, as we have lot of source, upgrading wxWidgets GUI to latest may need to change the source, we decided to go with wxWindows-2.4.2 as in Windows(VS2017/2019)

Comment: @Bhaskar, wx dev team gives a lot of effort to keep the old code as well as very old code to be backward compatible. ALL incompatible changes are properly documented qand gives the solution on how to fix such incompatibility. It is much prefer to upgrade and stay current if not to 3.1.5 (latest release), than to latest 3.0 release. You will save yourself a lot of headache.

Comment: Thank you Igor for your valuable suggestions, we will look into that !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can successfully run the configure phase by first performing `dnf install gtk2-devel`, and then configuring with `./configure --enable-gtk2`.

*However*, (not surprisingly), wx 2.4.2 will not successfully build on RHEL8 (I tried); there will be a bunch of compilation errors. Those are not impossible to fix, but I wonder if that's worth the trouble – there probably would be runtime errors and/or misbehaving GUI components at the next stage.

While I understand your strategy of choosing the old wx version that the application is known to work with on Windows, it seems to be the hard way in this case.

Comment: Thank you Lauri, configuration is successful with provided command and build processed without any compilation error but as you said we are facing lot of compilation errors in the source, anyway thanks for your help !